# Plotting a function in 3 dimensions within a domain

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics3d, complex, differential-geometry

In this paper:

https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/HypergeometricFunctions/COGP.pdf

Any help how to reproduce the plot in Figure:7

[image]

It’s the leading order of the complex function, Equation (4.3)

[image]

I have written as

`g[psi_]= 3/(4 psi * Conjugate[psi] * Log[Abs[5 psi ]]^2 ) * (1 - ((48 * Zeta[3.0] ) / (25* Log [Abs [5 psi]]^3 )))`

It’s written in the figure’s caption that $g_{\psi \bar{\psi}}$ has been plotted against $ \psi$ ( however it’s a 3D graph! ) in a certain region of arg $\psi$ .

Any help to reproduce that will be appreciated!

Edit:

My naive trail!

[image]

Comment: Holy function, Batman! .. or holy Batman function?

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricPlot3D`. This way, you can use polar coordiates in the first two coordinate dimensions and the function `g` for the third one. This would also produce theses nice mesh lines (which cannot be obtained by the `PlotRegion` option in `Plot3D`).

Comment: Does `ComplexPlot3D[g[\[Psi]], {\[Psi], -0.25 - 0.25 I, 0.25 + 0.25 I}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{\[Psi]}, 0 < Arg[\[Psi]] < 2 \[Pi]/5]]` help?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,  My problem with `parametricPlot3D` or `Plot3D` is that the function should be in two variables coordinates, and here g is a function in $\psi$  only. So plotting it against r and $\theta$ in polar coordinates maybe needs a change of coordinates which I’m not expert about, especially i have a region of $\psi$.

Comment: @ChrisK, never show it like that, till your joke, nice -:) Lol!

Comment: @murray, thanks, but no, cause `ComplexPlot` isn’t in MA9, the Mathematica version which i have. May be i will try by something like `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: Obviously, $\psi$ is meant to be a complex number, so it has a real and a complex part. That's your two real variables.

Comment: The article may have a typo. It states that $g_{\psi\psi}$ has a   logarithmic singularity at $\psi = 1$. Although there is a logarithmic singularity at $5 \psi = 1$.The pole is not shown at $\psi = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g[psi_] = 3/(4 psi*Conjugate[psi]*
      Log[Abs[5 psi]]^2)*(1 - (48*Zeta[3]/(25*Log[Abs[5 psi]]^3)));
```

The paper states that the plot is for `0 <= Arg[psi] < 2 Pi/5` and that the series expansions are valid for `Abs[psi] > 1`

```
ComplexExpand[
 0 <= Arg[psi] < 2 Pi/5 && Abs[psi] > 1, {psi},
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

(* 0 <= ArcTan[Re[psi], Im[psi]] < (2 π)/5 && Sqrt[Im[psi]^2 + Re[psi]^2] > 1 *)

ParametricPlot3D[
 {psiRe, psiIm, g[psiRe + I*psiIm]},
 {psiRe, 0, 4}, {psiIm, 0, 4},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{psiRe, psiIm, g, u, v},
   0 <= ArcTan[psiRe, psiIm] < 2 Pi/5 &&
    1 < Sqrt[psiRe^2 + psiIm^2] < 4] ,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re[ψ], Im[ψ], "g[ψ]"})]
```

[image]

The cowls do not show up.

Comment: Oh thanks anyway.  About the cups,  I think it’s something related to the intervals or so. Of course your graph is better than my trail in the Question ‘s edit  :-)